# Countable cofinality and closed sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal of countable cofinality we know that $F_1=\bigcup_{n<\omega} (\kappa_{2n},\kappa_{2n+1}]$ and $F_2=\bigcup_{n<\omega} (\kappa_{2\alpha+1},\kappa_{2\alpha}]$, where $\{\kappa_n\}_n$ is a cofinal sequence of cardinals less than $\kappa$, are two disjoint closed sets with cardinality $\kappa$.

But, if we apply the same argument in the case where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal of uncountable cofinality, we couldn't get a contradiction with the next fact?

$$\bigcap_{\alpha<\gamma} F_\alpha\neq \emptyset\, ,\;\; \forall \gamma<cf(\kappa)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use the same argument. Let $\lambda=\operatorname{cf}\kappa$, and let $\langle\kappa_\xi:\xi<\lambda\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence of cardinals cofinal in $\kappa$. Let $\Lambda$ be the set of limit ordinals less than $\lambda$; we can choose the sequence in such a way that $\kappa_\eta=\sup_{\xi<\eta}\kappa_\xi$ for each $\eta\in\Lambda$.

$$F_0=\bigcup\{(\kappa_{\eta+2n},\kappa_{\eta+2n+1}]:\eta\in\Lambda\text{ and }n\in\omega\}$$

and

$$F_1=\bigcup\{(\kappa_{\eta+2n+1},\kappa_{\eta+2n+2}]:\eta\in\Lambda\text{ and }n\in\omega\}\;;$$

the sets $F_0$ and $F_1$ are disjoint, but they’re not closed, because, for instance,

$$\kappa_\omega=\sup_{n<\omega}\kappa_{2n}=\sup_{n<\omega}\kappa_{2n+1}\in(\operatorname{cl}F_0)\cap\operatorname{cl}F_1\;.$$

Comment: Great answer! As always, thank you Mr. @Brian M. Scott!

Comment: @Ergonvi: You’re welcome!